# KTOR response with json format is not working

Tags: reactjs, ktor

1. 

```
 install(ServerContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
```

```
2.  json:  val format = Json { coerceInputValues = true; ignoreUnknownKeys = true;encodeDefaults = true   }. 
var response = format.encodeToString(response.body)
 call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, response)

3. text : tried with text like  call.respondText(response)
```

Expected :in the logs the response data is there. reactjs side there is no response.  Text or json response is empty. no cor issue . headers are good . tried with content type json and text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.